# Error: Uninitialized_public_client_application in angular after version 16 upgrade

Tags: angular-material, msal-angular

after upgrading to angular 16 from 15, new updates did not support msal v2 so updated it to the latest version i.e. v3, now getting below error in browser:

Error: uncaught (in promise): BrowserAuthError: uninitialized_public_client_application: you must call and await the initialize function before attempting to call any other MSAL API.

Can anyone suggest something please

I read documentation for migrating from msal 2 to 3, but adding those snippet to my application created more issues

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue as well after the upgrade.

Make sure that you initialize MSAL before making any authentication-related calls. Ensure that this initialization is completed before any other MSAL API calls.

```
import { MsalService } from '@azure/msal-angular';

constructor(private authService: MsalService) {
  this.authService.initialize();
}
```